# Error gazebo simulator in ros groovy

Tags: gazebo, simulation, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having problems when running: roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch, in my ros groovy environment. I have two ros, fuerte and groovy installed in ubuntu 12.04 precise. When I switch to fuerte, it runs perfectly, but whenever switch to groovy, it produces an error message.
Error:

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch 
... logging to /home/anshar/.ros/log/946e8346-c82c-11e2-8138-5c260a08367a/roslaunch-anshar-17672.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://anshar:47955/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo/gui)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [17686]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 946e8346-c82c-11e2-8138-5c260a08367a
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [17699]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [17713]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [17719]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.5.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.5.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world].
Set SDF value
  Version[1.2] to Version[1.3]
  Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
    $ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
Msg Waiting for masterterminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::InvalidNameException'
  what():  Character [] at element [8] is not valid in Graph Resource Name [gazebobo].  Valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, / and _.

Error [Connection.cc:477] Connection[0] Closed during Read
Aborted (core dumped)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::system::system_error'
  what():  End of file
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 17713, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/anshar/.ros/log/946e8346-c82c-11e2-8138-5c260a08367a/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/anshar/.ros/log/946e8346-c82c-11e2-8138-5c260a08367a/gazebo-2*.log
Aborted (core dumped)
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 17719, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/anshar/.ros/log/946e8346-c82c-11e2-8138-5c260a08367a/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/anshar/.ros/log/946e8346-c82c-11e2-8138-5c260a08367a/gazebo_gui-3*.log
^C[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

I need to ctrl -c to stop.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thank you

Anshar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63806/error-gazebo-simulator-in-ros-groovy/) by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2013-05-28

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2013-05-29**:
Having the same problem. Could be an ogre error as: source /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/setup.bash
[rospack] Error: stack/package ogre not found

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-05-29**:
After checking, my system doesn't have ogre and when trying to install from ogre wiki, found out that it doesn't support for precise 12.04. any clue would be great?

**Comment by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) on 2013-05-30**:
"Msg Waiting for masterterminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::InvalidNameException'"
I had a similar problem to this, but with the node name. There was a weird pointer allocation and I had to manually overwrite gazebo's ROS plugin to make it work. (in ROS package simulator_gazebo).

**Comment by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) on 2013-05-30**:
And I'm in Ubuntu 12.04 and have ogre running fine. It just wasn't in the right path. Try to look for it in your computer and if you find it change its path in the environment variable.

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2013-05-30**:
are you running dual ros installation?, fuerte and groovy?

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-07-09**:
Has anyone found a fix? I have the same issue on at least 4 different machines... and yet there are other computers in my lab that work just fine. All machines had Ubuntu 12.04 installed from scratch and they all have different hardware specs. I followed the exact same instructions every time!

**Comment by [t.pimentel](https://answers.ros.org/users/4923/t.pimentel/) on 2014-07-24**:
The recommended way to use Gazebo with ROS groovy (at least since June 2013, if I remember correctly) was not to use simulator_gazebo package that comes with ROS, but to install Gazebo as a standalone software from [http://gazebosim.org/ Gazebo Oficial Website].

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-07-24**:
Only true on Hydro and above; I'm using Groovy, which requires an older version of Gazebo that is packaged with ROS. However, I think I've figured out the reason: it appears that older version of Gazebo doesn't work very well on 32-bit operating systems.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-07-28**:
Gazebo had its forum, did you try to ask  your question there?

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-07-28**:
Yes, there were a couple of similar questions on the Gazebo Answers site. For reference, here they are: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3935/gazebo-15-crash-on-startup-invalidnameexception and http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5221/launching-gazebo-fails-with-ros-groovy-pr2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can now confidently assert that this error (specifically the `ros::InvalidNameException`) occurs when running Gazebo 1.5 on a 32-bit operating system. The issue can be resolved by moving to 64-bit or to Hydro, but I don't know of a fix for 32-bit Groovy.

---

Originally posted by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) with karma: 205 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0